# Exporting Amazon S3 Data using EMR into local database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr

has anyone ever exported S3 data from Amazon AWS into local database using EMR? I want to write a custom M/R solution that would extract certain data and parallel load into a local network database instance. I have not seen anything on Amazon website that states that that is possible or not. Lot of mentioning of moving the data within AWS instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say a "local network database", are you referring to a database on an EC2 instance or your local network?

Either way is possible - if you are using a non-EC2 or non-AWS database, just make sure to open up your security groups / firewall to make the necessary network connections.

As for loading data from S3 into your local database:

1. You can crunch data from S3 using EMR and convert it into CSV format using the mappers, and bulk import that into your database. This will likely be the fastest - since bulk import from CSV will allow the database to import data really fast.
2. You can use the EMR mappers to insert data directly into the database - but I don't recommend this approach. With multiple mappers writing to the database directly, you can easily overload the database and cause stalls and the process to fail.

Comment: Thanks Suman, yeah I am referring to local network database. I was planning to insert directly from reducer where I can control the parallelism factor that way making sure I don't overwhelm the database.

Comment: OK, that should definitely work. Why the reducer though - if you don't need to aggregate the raw data, then you could do it straight in the mapper. Of course, if you need to use the reducer step, then definitely do it in the reducer.

Comment: Btw, I've done both #1 and #2 :) so that's why I know it works.

Comment: The reducer allows me to specify how many connections to RDMBS I will have.  If I run with 100 reducers and have speculative execution turned off, then only 100 connections to RDBMS will be established. It is probably possible to do this with custom InputFormat and do this in the mapper but I would have to implement custom InputFormat and play around with S3 input splits (basically passing multiple splits to the reader).